# Adding a and + or constraint in gurobipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gurobi

I am new to gurobi. I have a list of paired variables(paired_list) like below and a resultant gurobi variable(my_res).
`paired_list = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],...]`.

Here a,b,c,d,e,f are also gurobi variables.

I have to set a constraint which is a combination of and and or operator as below

```
my_res = [(a and b) or (c and d) or (e and f)...].
```

How can I translate this into a gurobi constraint in python?

Rough gurobi translation for this would be

```
model.addConstr(my_res == or_(and_(a,b),and_(c,d),and(e,f)))
```

Comment: Are a,b,c,d,e,f binary decision variables?

Comment: Yes. all variables are binary including resultant

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is a general question about integer programming, which belongs on math.stackexchange.com or compsci.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you want:

```
paired_list = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]
result = any(all(i) for i in paired_list)
```